# Adding an IBOutlet to custom class

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I'm learning iOS and am new to the concept of IBOutlets - so I'm making a simple app in an attempt to learn how it works.

**The problem:**
I created an interface using a Storyboard and want to hook it up to an IBOutlet in my custom class ("TapCounter") in order to access (and be able to set) its text field. However when trying to hook my class' `@property (nonatomic, weak, readwrite) IBOutlet UILabel* numberOfTapsTextField;`
 up to the UILabel in the Storyboard the line does not want to attach to the label.

Here is an image of the situation: http://gyazo.com/0050ef0a78772adcad214cdc4603f932 (Dragging a line from the hollow circle next to the @property to the label in the Storyboard does not snap to it).

I have not modified anything of the boilerplate code except for that I added #import "TapCounter.h" in  viewController.m

This feels like it should be a very simple thing - but again; I am new to this.

## EDIT

Have I got this idea wrong? **Should all IBOutlets be in the viewController** of a view (and simply be accessed by other custom classes)?

Comment: Have you changed your custom object class to TapCounter in storyboard?

Comment: TapCounter should be subclassed from UIViewController.

Comment: Nope, the UILabel is an UILabel, why would I change it to be something else? @Greg

Comment: I tried changing my class to inherit from UIViewcontroller, it did not work @Cy-4AH

Comment: @AxelK TapCounter is NSObject and this is your custom class. It needs to be added to storyboard and class needs to be change to appropriate one.

Answer (score 3):

It work like this:

1. create a `CustomView` class
2. add a `view` in you storyBoard
3. set **class** for this custom view as `CustomView` in identity inspector cmd+opt+3
4. Create an IBOutlate of your component inside `customView`
5. Link those component with respective outlet

Refer Image: [image]